# DuplicatedFileException when import .lar

Tags: liferay

I'm replicating a Liferay portal (6.1.30-ee-ga3) in my own server, and I exported Public Pages from original source, but when I'm trying to import in mine I get this exception, and I don't know whats wrong...

```
11:48:18,347 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-15][ImportLayoutsAction:127] com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.PortletDataException: com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.DuplicateFileException: cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123 com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.PortletDataException: com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.DuplicateFileException: cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.BasePortletDataHandler.importData(BasePortletDataHandler.java:152) 
    at com.liferay.portal.lar.PortletImporter.importPortletData(PortletImporter.java:1091) 
    at com.liferay.portal.lar.PortletImporter.importPortletData(PortletImporter.java:1031) 
    at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.doImportLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:792) 
    at com.liferay.portal.lar.LayoutImporter.importLayouts(LayoutImporter.java:149) 
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutLocalServiceImpl.java:1534) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceVirtualLayoutsAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceVirtualLayoutsAdvice.java:175) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113) 
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.invoke(LayoutLocalServiceStagingAdvice.java:124) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.importLayouts(Unknown Source) 
    at com.liferay.portal.service.impl.LayoutServiceImpl.importLayouts(LayoutServiceImpl.java:715) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy110.importLayouts(Unknown Source) 
    at com.liferay.portal.service.LayoutServiceUtil.importLayouts(LayoutServiceUtil.java:536) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.layoutsadmin.action.ImportLayoutsAction.processAction(ImportLayoutsAction.java:89) 
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortletRequestProcessor.process(PortletRequestProcessor.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.StrutsPortlet.processAction(StrutsPortlet.java:214) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:71) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.PortletFilterUtil.doFilter(PortletFilterUtil.java:48) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invoke(InvokerPortletImpl.java:616) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.invokeAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:647) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.InvokerPortletImpl.processAction(InvokerPortletImpl.java:315) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.MonitoringPortlet.processAction(MonitoringPortlet.java:184) 
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processPortletRequest(LayoutAction.java:963) 
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.processLayout(LayoutAction.java:701) 
    at com.liferay.portal.action.LayoutAction.execute(LayoutAction.java:262) 
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431) 
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236) 
    at com.liferay.portal.struts.PortalRequestProcessor.process(PortalRequestProcessor.java:182) 
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196) 
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:432) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.callParentService(MainServlet.java:559) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.MainServlet.service(MainServlet.java:536) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:314) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:107) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.FriendlyURLServlet.service(FriendlyURLServlet.java:136) 
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:73) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.strip.StripFilter.processFilter(StripFilter.java:355) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.gzip.GZipFilter.processFilter(GZipFilter.java:123) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.secure.SecureFilter.processFilter(SecureFilter.java:314) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.i18n.I18nFilter.processFilter(I18nFilter.java:259) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.etag.ETagFilter.processFilter(ETagFilter.java:86) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.jsoncontenttype.JSONContentTypeFilter.processFilter(JSONContentTypeFilter.java:42) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.autologin.AutoLoginFilter.processFilter(AutoLoginFilter.java:250) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.sso.ntlm.NtlmPostFilter.processFilter(NtlmPostFilter.java:83) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.sharepoint.SharepointFilter.processFilter(SharepointFilter.java:88) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.processFilter(BaseFilter.java:169) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.virtualhost.VirtualHostFilter.processFilter(VirtualHostFilter.java:191) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:738) 
    at com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.processFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:57) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:59) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDoFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:207) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:109) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:168) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.processDirectCallFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:188) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilterChain.doFilter(InvokerFilterChain.java:96) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.filters.invoker.InvokerFilter.doFilter(InvokerFilter.java:107) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) 
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) 
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) 
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) 
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) 
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008) 
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) 
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
Caused by: com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.DuplicateFileException: cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.validateFile(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:2238) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.validateFile(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:2263) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceImpl.java:151) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1387.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy714.addFileEntry(Unknown Source) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLFileEntryLocalServiceWrapper.addFileEntry(DLFileEntryLocalServiceWrapper.java:292) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1387.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.bean.ClassLoaderBeanHandler.invoke(ClassLoaderBeanHandler.java:67) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy715.addFileEntry(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1387.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302.addFileEntry(Unknown Source) 
    at com.liferay.portal.repository.liferayrepository.LiferayLocalRepository.addFileEntry(LiferayLocalRepository.java:144) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.impl.DLAppLocalServiceImpl.addFileEntry(DLAppLocalServiceImpl.java:248) 
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1493.invoke(Unknown Source) 
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:117) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.DefaultTransactionExecutor.execute(DefaultTransactionExecutor.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.transaction.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:52) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.proceed(ServiceBeanMethodInvocation.java:113) 
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAopProxy.invoke(ServiceBeanAopProxy.java:218) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.doInvoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:62) 
    at com.liferay.portal.security.pacl.PACLInvocationHandler.invoke(PACLInvocationHandler.java:51) 
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy298.addFileEntry(Unknown Source) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.service.DLAppLocalServiceUtil.addFileEntry(DLAppLocalServiceUtil.java:196) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.lar.DLPortletDataHandlerImpl.importFileEntry(DLPortletDataHandlerImpl.java:434) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.lar.DLPortletDataHandlerImpl.importFileEntry(DLPortletDataHandlerImpl.java:265) 
    at com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.lar.DLPortletDataHandlerImpl.doImportData(DLPortletDataHandlerImpl.java:2091) 
    at com.liferay.portal.kernel.lar.BasePortletDataHandler.importData(BasePortletDataHandler.java:148)
```

When I open .lar file and search for `cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123` I find it in 3 xml files, 2 of them are a 1.0 files and have different data (different uuid) and the last one is an article.xml, which references to one of uuid, I tried to change name of it, if I change on 3 files I have same error with new filename, but if I change in 1.0 file which have different uuid than article.xml reference I have exactly same error.

Comment: It always helps to add the exact Liferay version if you post a stacktrace. Line numbers differ between versions.

Comment: @TobiasLiefke ok, I added it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing from your error log:

In one of your *Document and Media* folders you've got a document `cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123`. And in your LAR a document with that name exists as well, but with a different *UUID*. Which means both documents were created separately (none of them is an import of the other). Liferay will only overwrite existing files with the same UUID - not with the same name.

What you can do: delete the file `cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123` on the target server and restart the import.

Another possible reason is that your original server contains already two files with the same name. No matter how that has happened - you will have to rename one of the files - either in the LAR or on the original server.

Comment: Ok but how can I find this file? It's a clean portal with some hooks, themes and layouts installed, but if I try import in a real clean portal I had same error...

Comment: The LAR file is just a ZIP with your documents and many XML metadata files. Extract the ZIP file and scan the XML files for `cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123` in the content.

Comment: I changed `cons_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123` to `cons2_insti_org_01_bn_jpg_200x123` and get same error but with this new name, when I search for original name I found it in 3 files, 2 in 1.0 files and last in article.xml

Comment: The occurrences in the `1.0` files are the interesting ones (the one in the article.xml is a reference only). Each file entry should only have one `1.0`. You should check the differences between both files.